# Strong typedef / Compiler-enforced Apps Hungarian in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm not sure what terminology to use here, but this question gives an introduction to my problem:
[Language with apps hungarian support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927288/language-with-apps-hungarian-support)

I thought that with the new user-defined literals in C++11, something resembling what the poster linked to above calls "strong typedefs" would be introduced, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I hope I'm wrong, that would be convenient. :)

To be specific, I want this:

```
typedef int column;
typedef int row;

void myColumnFunc(column)
{
}

main()
{
    column myColumn = 0;
    row myRow = 0;
    int myInt = 0;

    myColumnFunc(myColumn); // OK
    myColumnFunc(myRow); // I want a compiler error here
    myColumnFunc(myInt); // I want a compiler error here

}
```

If there are compiler-specific options for this, please mention it, but I'm working cross-platform so it's not really a solution.

I can think of a couple of workarounds (classes, enum classes), but a "strong typedef" would be ideal.

My questions are:
1. Is there a way to enforce this that I've overlooked.
2. If not, I'd be interested in idiomatic workarounds, if there are any. If not, I'll probably use enum classes for this.

Comment: why not just make a class called column that is blank and inherits from int?

Comment: @marsh: You can't inherit from primitive types in C++.

Comment: There exists [`BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/serialization/doc/strong_typedef.html), is that a possibility for you?

Comment: @Wintermute: Thanks for the suggestion, I wasn't aware of boost strong typedef before I posted this question. However, I'm hesitant to depend on boost on such a fundamental level.

Answer (score 3):

There are two options :

- [boost strong_typedef](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/serialization/doc/strong_typedef.html)
- use c++11 strong typedef enums (see [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Strongly_typed_enumerations))

In both cases, you are going to introduce a new type, and the compiler will complain if you pass wrong "value" to the function.

---

The example with strongly typedef enum :

```
enum class column
{
    ONE = 1,
    TWO,
    FIVE
};

typedef int row;

void myColumnFunc(column)
{
}

int main()
{
    column myColumn = column::TWO;
    row myRow = 0;
    int myInt = 0;

    myColumnFunc(myColumn); // OK
    //myColumnFunc(myRow);                                   // I want a compiler error here
    //myColumnFunc(myInt);                                   // I want a compiler error here
}
```

Comment: It looks like you cannot do arithmetic on `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF`ed values, or any other operations that are defined on the original type.

Comment: @n.m. No, you can't. If you need that, you have to implement those operators yourself. But I don't see that being asked for in the question

Comment: @BЈовић: Can't upvote, but thanks for the input. I'll probably go with enum classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the options provided by boost (perhaps [boost units](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_units.html) fits better than the already mentioned boost strong typedef), the basics of rolling your own is something like the following:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename tag, typename base = int>
class tagged {
public:
    explicit tagged(const base& val) : val_(val) {}
    explicit operator base() const { return val_; }
private:
    base val_;
};

struct column_tag{};
struct row_tag{};
typedef tagged<column_tag> column;
typedef tagged<row_tag> row;

template<typename tag, typename base>
tagged<tag, base> operator+(const tagged<tag, base>& a, const tagged<tag, base>& b) {
    return tagged<tag, base>{static_cast<base>(a) + static_cast<base>(b)};
}

void myColumnFunc(column){}

int main()
{
    column myColumn{2};
    row    myRow{1};
    myColumnFunc(myColumn);
//    myColumnFunc(myRow); // error: could not convert ‘myRow’ from ‘row {aka tagged<row_tag>}’ to ‘column {aka tagged<column_tag>}’
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(column{2} + column{3}) << std::endl;
//    std::cout << static_cast<int>(column{2} + row{2}) << std::endl; // error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘column {aka tagged<column_tag>}’ and ‘row {aka tagged<row_tag>}’)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll have to take some time to completely understand your suggestion and if it has any side effects for me before I decide whether to use it. I'm not sure this is code that I want to return to in six months, but it does do what I asked. I'm too new to upvote, but thanks!