# Is assignment the only difference between derived types and subtypes in Ada?

Tags: ada, derived-types, subtyping

I have read that derived types are completely different types than their respective parents, however the do inherit all their parents' operations.

In other words, you can pass a derived type `A` to a operation that receives as a parameter a type `B` which is `A`'s parent. However, you can't assign a variable of type `A` to one of type `B` and vice versa.

According to the above, the only difference between derived types and subtypes is the assignment. Is that right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677752/derived-types-and-sub-types-in-ada ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Derived types only inherit the **primitive operations** of the type they are derived from.

Technically the type derivation creates a new set of primitive operations, so you can't "pass a derived type `A` to a operation that receives as a parameter a type `B` which is `A`'s parent".  But the compiler creates operations of the same name and implementation, which work on type `A` from the primitive operations of type `B`.  You can for example remove the inherited operations by explicitly declaring them abstract.

Comment: What does it mean exactly primitive operations in this context?

Comment: The definition in section 3.2.3 in the language reference manual: http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-2-3.html

Comment: As far as I understand, all operations of a type T are primitive operations of that type, am I right? If not, could give me an example of an operation of a type T that is not considered primitive?

Comment: An operation on the type declared in a different package.

Comment: Then, the main difference (apart from the assignment) is that a subtype of T can be used in all T operations, primitive or not. So, these would be the two differences, is that right?

Comment: You could probably say so, but read the language reference manual, if you want to be sure.  I see subtypes as subsets, and types as types (no matter if they are derived or not).